# how to understand this sentence 'Delightful though it is to gloat'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does it mean

1. the thing is good enough and the person who said it can be gloating.
2. although the thing is good and delightful, it shouldn't be gloated.

Comment: It's very hard to tell without knowing the context surrounding the quote. Is that the full sentence? If so can you give us the sentence before and the one after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gloating has a negative connotation in most contexts.  I think the author is saying, it may be delightful to gloat but it's not appropriate.